# Import store using createContex mobximport store as props createContext mobx

Tags: javascript, createcontext

there is a class that unites all classes of the store. You need to pass this class to app.js so that you can get it in any of the files using createContext

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your using React. React Context will help you to manage state when you build you apps. [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Kent Dodds has given nice work in [this](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively) presentation,must read.

And [here](https://habr.com/ru/post/522896/) is Russian translation.